# Flutter and Cloud Firestore how to access 2nd level category list

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I have a firebase database that is built like this.

```
MainCategories - Cat 1 - 
                        - SubCategories -
                                    - Sub Cat 1
                                    - Sub Cat 2
                 Cat 2 - SubCategories -
                                    - Sub Cat 1
                                    - Sub Cat 2
                                    - Sub Cat 3
                 Cat 3 - SubCategories -
                                    - Sub Cat 1
                 Cat 4 - SubCategories -
                                    - Sub Cat 1
                                    - Sub Cat 2
                                    - Sub Cat 3
```

I am trying to do a list builder on my homepage to to populate the Main Categories, I have managed to do this with

```
Query collectionReference = Firestore.instance.collection("mainCategories").orderBy("title");
```

Then I have a list view builder that is working fine for the main Categories

```
                      ListView.builder(
                      itemCount: snapshot.length,
                      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                        return InkWell(
                          onTap: () => passData(snapshot[index]),
                          child: MainCard(
                            title: snapshot[index].data["title"],
                            subtitle: snapshot[index].data["subTitle"],
                            image: snapshot[index].data["image"],
                          ),
                        );
                      }),
                ),
```

Im passing the data with

```
passData(DocumentSnapshot snap) {
    Navigator.of(context).push(
        MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Category(snapshot: snap,)));
  }
```

Which I am not even sure if its needed.

IN the Category widget I am looking to build another list view of the sub categories

So in this case if they selected the 2nd category it should show you a list view of the 3 sub categories.

I am not sure if I am passing the data right to begin with and in the Category widget I am sure I am not querying it correctly.

```
Query collectionReference = Firestore.instance.collection("subCategories");
```

I am looking to see how to populate that 2nd level of categories in the listview builder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your subcategories actually implemented as nested subcollections in Firestore, the query looks more like this:

```
Query subCategoriesQuery = Firestore.instance
    .collection("mainCategories")
    .document(cat)
    .collection(subCat)
```

You will need to provide a value for both `cat` as the name of the top level category document, and a value for `subCat` for the name of the subcategory subcollection.

Comment: But if I am navigating in from the Main category, can I pass the index value in? For example if I click on Cat 2 I want the category page to display the cat 2 sub categories.

Comment: That sounds like a different problem than making the correct query.  I don't really know enough Flutter to answer this followup, I can only tell you how to make the query.

Comment: Also the documents are auto generated ID, what would define the "cat" is that the  ID?

Comment: You're going to need to remember that value somehow, or query for the document you want using what you know about it fields.

Comment: Ok perfect. I hardcoded it to test and it worked.. thank you!